# TFTP server written in C - Binary diff at the client end shows a difference but not always

Tags: c, sockets, cmp, tftp

I have written a tftp server in C . The tftp client I am using is the native linux client . The file transfer seems to happen correctly . The sent and received file sizes appear to be the same . But if I do "cmp" on both the files there is a difference . I have attached the function which sends "512 bytes" of data or less to the client.  I am not sure if there is any padding being introduced but I don't know where that might happen .

```
void send_next_data (int client_id)
{
int opcode = 0;
int block_id = 0;
unsigned long bytes_left = 0;
unsigned long offset = 0;
unsigned long file_length = 0;
char *ptr = buffer_send;
int total_bytes = 0;
int result;
int i;


opcode = 3;
client_list[client_id].prev_blockid += 1;
block_id = client_list[client_id].prev_blockid;

opcode = htons(opcode);
block_id = htons(block_id);
bzero(buffer_send,520);

memcpy(ptr, &opcode, sizeof(uint16_t));
ptr += sizeof(uint16_t);

memcpy(ptr, &block_id, sizeof(uint16_t));
ptr += sizeof(uint16_t);

total_bytes += 4;

offset = client_list[client_id].offset;
file_length =  client_list[client_id].file_length;

if(offset < file_length)
{
    bytes_left = file_length - offset;
    if(bytes_left > 512)
    {
        memcpy(ptr, &client_list[client_id].file[offset], 512);
        ptr += 512;
        total_bytes += 512;
        client_list[client_id].offset += 512;
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(ptr, &client_list[client_id].file[offset], bytes_left);
        ptr += bytes_left;
        total_bytes += bytes_left;
        client_list[client_id].offset += bytes_left;
    }
}


result = sendto(socket_list[client_id], buffer_send, total_bytes, 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&client_list[client_id].clientAddr, client_list[client_id].clientAddrLen);
printf(" total_bytes sent = %d, result = %d , client id = %d, send on fd = %d\n", total_bytes, result, client_id, socket_list[client_id]);
    //  printf(" Error = %d\n", errno);
}
```

I copy the data from the binary file onto a buffer and then use offsets on this buffer to transfer 512 or less bytes of data . To test if the file has been copied to the buffer properly ,I wrote this buffer back to a "test" file and a cmp between the source and this "test" file says there is no difference.

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
client_list[n].file_length = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

client_list[n].file = malloc((client_list[n].file_length+100) * sizeof(char));

bzero(client_list[n].file, client_list[n].file_length+100);
i=0;
    c = getc(fp) ;
while (!(feof(fp)))
{
   client_list[n].file[i] = c;
   c = getc(fp);
   i++;
}

printf(" Number of bytes read from file = %ld , size of file = %ld \n", i, client_list[n].file_length);

send_next_data(n);

fclose(fp);

fp = fopen("test", "wb");
fwrite(client_list[n].file, 1,client_list[n].file_length ,fp);
fclose(fp);
```

I generate binary files using 
         `time dd if=/dev/urandom of=random-file bs=1 count=xxxx` and send it . For a file size of 77940 bytes , cmp says that the first diff appears at byte 44393 . Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: What about the code that saves on the client side?

Comment: It's the native tftp linux client . I have not written the client . So I don't expect a problem there.

Comment: What are the actual characters that are different?  Is it a question of escaping or signedness?

Comment: @AdamLiss Since I am testing with binary files I am not sure how to find the actual characters .   `cmp -b`  gives this 
`random-file ../tftptest1/random-file differ: byte 44393, line 175 is   0 ^@ 377 M-^?`  . I don't think it makes much sense

Comment: Interesting.  I don't see anything in RFC 1350 about escaping, but it's probably not a coincidence that one file has ASCII 0 and the other has ASCII 255 (octal 377 = hex FF = dec 255).  Does it make a difference if you change `char *ptr` to `unsigned char *ptr` (and then make whatever additional adjustments that necessitates)?

Comment: @AdamLiss I changed it to unsigned char * but it doesn't make a difference . But this is a good clue to investigate further

Comment: @AdamLiss Thanks I figured it out . I was not setting the mode as binary on the client side . By default the mode was netascii . Thanks for the pointer

Comment: @Ash Glad you got it working.  Thanks for following up!